# How can I retrieve each row from datable and write each row to a separate text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to retrieve the selected row to a separate text file I tried but my code just retrieves all the rows not the selected one

I'am wondering if there is a way to check the row that I want to retrieve it I mean I want to choose from rows
I displayed the datatable and i want choose by selection

please how can I do the selection process???

```
 <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- <th>-</th>-->
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>ORDBUS</th>
                <th>ORDSER</th>
                <th>SEQUEN</th>
                <th>HEUDEB</th>
                <th>HEUFIN</th>

                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                <tr class="active-row">
                    <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>-->
                    <td>@row["DATMVT"]</td>
                    <td>@row["ORDBUS"]</td>
                    <td>@row["ORDSER"]</td>
                    <td>@row["SEQUEN"]</td>
                    <td>@row["HEUDEB"]</td>
                    <td>@row["HEUFIN"]</td>

                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=Edit>EDIT</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script> $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
            var selData = table.rows(".selected").data();
            alert(selData.length);
        });</script>
   
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ConvertToTextfile", "Display", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGetData" />
    }
```

this is the view

```
 public ActionResult ConvertToTextfile()

        {
            string mySQL;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySQL = "Select * From MOUVEMSSE.Mouvem11 ";
            string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dsn_AS400"];
            string conn_string = connect + "UID=" + HttpContext.Session["Username"] + ";PWD=" + HttpContext.Session["Password"] + ";";

            db_tools.sg_connStr = conn_string;
            connection = db_tools.Connect();
            table = db_tools.ExecuteSelectCommand(mySQL, CommandType.Text);
            myDataSet.Tables.Add();


            string folderLocation = @"C:\Users\zarai\source\repos\Sms_Chauffeur\Sms_Chauffeur\Extractedfiles"; // your path to save the files 

            for (int i = 0; i<table.Rows.Count; i++)  // iterate each rows to get the value
           {
               string fileName = folderLocation + "\\" + "File-" + i + ".txt";  // file name for saving each row
               string contents = "";
               foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)  // iteate each column to get its corresponding value
                   contents += table.Rows[i][col].ToString() + "    ";  // concatenating the contents

               System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, contents);  // create a text file and copy the contents
           }

            return View("data Extracted sucssessfuly");
        }
this is the controller
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar9to.png) this is the output

Comment: It would be nice if you pass the id for selected row and filter the from db as you are extracting it from db itself.

Comment: I am not using sql I am using AS400 IBM Database so how can I do it without id if you have an idea, please ??

Comment: you have a query written, so surely it is coming from a database. You need to add a where clause for the specific row you are filtering.

Comment: Could you please give me a code example?

Comment: you need to keep the database Id in the table. Upon selection you need to pass that to your method and filter the database with that id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to only retrieve the selected row from the table and save it in a text file. To do this, you need to use JavaScript to get the selected row data and pass it to the server to save it. Here is an updated version of the code:

View:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th>-</th>-->
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>ORDBUS</th>
            <th>ORDSER</th>
            <th>SEQUEN</th>
            <th>HEUDEB</th>
            <th>HEUFIN</th>

            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            <tr class="active-row">
                <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>-->
                <td>@row["DATMVT"]</td>
                <td>@row["ORDBUS"]</td>
                <td>@row["ORDSER"]</td>
                <td>@row["SEQUEN"]</td>
                <td>@row["HEUDEB"]</td>
                <td>@row["HEUFIN"]</td>

                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=Edit>EDIT</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
            var selData = table.rows(".selected").data();
            if (selData.length > 0) {
                var data = JSON.stringify(selData[0]);  // get the selected row data as a string
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("ConvertToTextfile", "Display")",
                    data: { rowData: data },  // pass the selected row data to the server
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert("Data extracted successfully.");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Please select a row first.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConvertToTextfile", "Display", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGetData" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
```

public ActionResult ConvertToTextfile(string rowData)
{
DataRow selectedRow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rowData);  // convert the string back to a DataRow

```
string folderLocation = @"C:\Users\zarai\source\repos\Sms_Chauffeur\Sms_Chauffeur\Extractedfiles"; // your path to save the files
```